# React-Native buffer global does not exist please consider using

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, buffer

I have a react native project. I don't know why sometimes "buffer global does not exist please consider using" appear in the screen. but when I npm install and yarn install it will disappear. today I don't know why npm install and yarn install method can't disappear this red screen.

[image]